WireGuard - Server Through Gnome Network Manager?
Can a WireGuard server be setup through Gnome network-manager? with a wireguard.conf file - no terminal or other program needed.
I need 3 clients to be able to connect to the server.
Internet traffic won't be routed. I just need them to connect to the server machine.

Network manager is not designed to set up multiple wireguard client connection configurations.
